# Searching files in the server and searching string inside the source code

Tags: search, amazon-ec2, file-search, coda

Are there software that enables you to search files or string inside your sourcecode that's on the server?

The text editor I am currently using is Coda by Panic and the server I am using is Amazon EC2. I wanted to search a "string" inside a file and I also wanted to search a certain file (eg style.css).

Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `grep` from terminal with `-r` recursive option.

```
$ grep -r "string" /folderToSearch/
```

Or search a single file

```
$ grep "string" /folder/filename.ext
```

Comment: Thanks man! this worked for me and this will be very handy! really appreciate it.